# Finding a Row Number based upon a value within a known column?

Tags: microsoft-excel, lookup

I have a workbook that's set out in a fairly specific way when imported.  And I'm one lookup away from having them quickly and easily sort itself out into a more readable form.

However, without using a huge IF function I'm struggling.

I've used Match to find out a column number.  In each column there are numbers ranging from 1-26.  These numbers never repeat in the same column, but across all columns they do.

So I'm trying to find out how I can make it return the Row Number of each value, so I can use INDEX to pull off a secondary bit of data.

I've attached an example of what I mean.  I'm trying to make it return me the name of the animal based upon whether there is a corresponding number in the row.  In the sample I'm looking at, I'm aiming to have Donkey next to "Name 1"
, Mouse next to "Name 2" and so on.  If I changed the Part No. to 501, I'd want it to return me Cat instead of Donkey.

[Sample Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hZdQy.png)

Maybe a solution in VBA is best for this?  I'm still learning that side of things however.  Maybe I'm just overthinking this and it's actually easier than I'm making it!  Certainly seems like it should be.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I am missing something because I definitely think you are overthinking this.

To get a row number, `=ROW()`

Updated per OP feedback, use `MATCH` to get the row. This only works gor the first match.

For all rows, you use an array function:

`=INDEX($B$3:$B$8, SMALL(IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH($A$3:$A$8, $G$4, 0)), MATCH(ROW($A$3:$A$8), ROW($A$3:$A$8)), ""), ROWS($A$1:A1)))`

Pasting this formula in H4, then selecting H5 and H6, then pressing Ctrl + Shift + Enter should give you Donkey, Cat, Dog

Comment: If I could highlight the exact cell each time than yes, that would work.

However I'm looking at automating it.  So in my example I want it to tell me which Row the 1 appears on for the "500" column, if I change the number 500 to 501, I'd like it to tell me which number row the 1 appears in that "501" column.

I could then use =INDEX(array,row,2) and it would give me the animal.  Just finding the row out is problematic.  As I said, finding and automating the column number based on the 500 number is easy.  Thought this would be simple.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: @A Brough Use Match for that.  Match(501,A1:A30,0) will return the row number if found (it is actually an index that it returns, but if the match range starts on the first row then the index will be the row number)